# ¿cómo saber cuando se utilizo 2 veces una plantilla comprada en template monster?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, template, wordpress-theme

¿cómo sabe un sitio como template monster cuando una plantilla se usó en 2 sitios diferentes pagando solo una vez los derechos de uso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como puedes ver en [esta fuente](http://www.daycounter.com/Articles/Verifying-Stolen-Code.phtml), las detecciones profesionales se basan en las ciencias computacionales para detectar con algoritmos estadísticos las violaciones a los derechos de uso, para el caso que planteas, si bien el código php no está directamente disponible, los resultados que produce sí, es muy sencillo hallar coincidencias textuales en muchos de los archivos incluidos, conteniendo pero no limitándose a:

- imágenes
- hojas de estilo
- scripts
- metadatos
- constantes
- cadenas internacionalizadas
- código fuente html

Entre las herramientas profesionales para detectar código robado podemos hallar:

- [Google alerts](http://www.google.com/alerts)
- [Copyscape](http://www.copyscape.com/)

Para remover código robado de las búsquedas de Google como parte de la DMCA puedes usar:

- [Google webmasters tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home)

para acelerar ese proceso en el caso de sitios es buena práctica registrarlos en [Google Search Authorship](http://www.google.com/insidesearch/features/authorship/index.html).

Para removerlo del servicio de hosting deberás de contactar de manera personal a la empresa que provea ese servicio, la puedes hallar fácilmente buscando la dirección del sitio ofensor en el buscador de "[who is hosting this](http://www.whoishostingthis.com/)", los sitios de hosting seguramente colaborarán contigo incluso antes de tener una demanda legal formal ya que quieren evitar aparecer listados mediante sus ip's en los servidores proxy a nivel mundial, que dicho sea de paso, esas gremio comunica las transgresiones rápidamente y quitar tu sitio de la lista negra normalmente tarda por lo menos una semana.

**Si crees que alguno de tus empleados ha usado un recurso por el que pagaste no dudes en comunicarte con el soporte de template monster** que seguramente te darán muchos consejos legales pertinentes. Seguramente no te compartirán información acerca de las medidas de seguridad que toman, pero no se quedarán con los brazos cruzados ante este tipo de delitos informáticos.